# Pointer to an array of n element of type int(strange addresses)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I wanted to make sure that I understand the concept of the pointer to an `array` of `n` elements, for example: `int (*myarr)[10]; //myarr is a pointer to an array that can hold 10 integer`

I've tried the following code:

```
void main(){
    int arr[][3] = { { 10, 20, 50 }, { 30, 60, 90 }, { 22, 92, 63 } };
        int(*arrptr)[3]; /* a pointer to an array of 3 ints*/
        int *ip = arr[0];
        arrptr = arr;
        int index;
        for (index = 0; index < 9; index++)
        {
            printf("[ %d ][ %p ]\n\n", *ip, ip);ip++;
        }

        for (index = 0; index < 3; index++)
        {
            printf("%x <-> %p,%d\n", *arrptr, arrptr,**arrptr);
            arrptr++;
        }
    }
```

and I got that

> ```
> *[ 10 ][ 001BFA40 ]*
>
> [ 20 ][ 001BFA44 ]
>
> [ 50 ][ 001BFA48 ]
>
> *[ 30 ][ 001BFA4C ]*
>
> [ 60 ][ 001BFA50 ]
>
> [ 90 ][ 001BFA54 ]
>
> *[ 22 ][ 001BFA58 ]*
>
> [ 92 ][ 001BFA5C ]
>
> [ 63 ][ 001BFA60 ]
>
> *1bfa40* <-> *001BFA40*,10
> 1bfa4c <-> 001BFA4C,30
> 1bfa58 <-> 001BFA58,22
> ```

As I understand, the `arrptr` holds the whole address which the array is pointing to. This would mean that the pointer can move freely in these ranges of addresses.

But, why is the address value that holds `arrptr` equal to the address that holds the value of `arr[0]`?

In other words: I know it's normal that `*arrptr` holds the address of `arr[0]`, but the address of `arrptr` that contains the place where the `arrptr` will point to is the same where `arr[0]` ?!

Comment: You never print out "*the address value that holds `arrptr`*", as you never use `&arrptr`. Please be more precise in your wording, to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: %p is not enough to print the address without using the & ? @alk

Comment: No. Please see my second answer on this. `%p` is used to print a `void`-pointer's value.  That's all.

Comment: If Binky (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pmWojisM_E) would help? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array is a contiguous storage area. So using your code snippet these expressions

`&arr`, `arr`, `arr[0]`, `&arr[0]`, and `&arr[0][0]` provide the same address of the storage memory occupied by the array. All them point to the first byte of the storage area.

Let's consider for example this statement

```
printf("%x <-> %p,%d\n", *arrptr, arrptr,**arrptr);
```

`arrptr` is a pointer having type `int ( * )[3];` . Dereferencing this pointer `*arrptr` you will get array of type `int[3]` that in turn is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element that is this expression will have type `int *` and the both `arrptr` and `*arrptr` yield the same value. That is the value itself is not changed. It is the type of the expression that is changed.:)

Thus as `*arrptr` has type `int *` and it is a pointer (after implicit converiosn of the corresponding one-dimensional array; C does not have references to objects as C++ has) then expression `**arrptr` yields an object of type `int`. According to the code snippet logic it is the first element of each row of the two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

`*arrptr` is equal (same type, same value) to `arrptr[0]`.  Since you've assigned `arrptr = arr` that also means `*arrptr` is equal to `*arr`.

Incidentally, using `%x` to print a pointer technically gives undefined behaviour (as `%x` is for an `unsigned` integral value).  Use `%p` instead.   Similarly, when using `%p` it is advisable to convert the pointer being printed to `(void *)`.

Comment: "*advisable*"? If not doing so the code runs into undefiend behaviour.

Comment: why %p give me the same address as %x? %x gives me the hex number contained in the *arrptr which is equivalent to &arrptr (by using %p) ?@Peter

Comment: that what  i mean @alk

Comment: @YahiaFarghaly: On a 86_64bit machine `x` give you 32bits of data whereas `p` gives you 64bits.

Comment: @YahiaFarghaly: The is **no** `&arrptr` all over the code you show. It's value never gets printed!

Answer (score 1):

> why the address value that holds `arrptr` is equal to the address that holds the value of `arr[0]`

The address of an array always equals the address of its first element.

For  any

```
T a[n];  /* n > 0 */
```

the expression

```
&a == &a[0]
```

is true.

---

Also please note that in C a "2D" array is just an array of arrays.

Comment: @YahiaFarghaly: So then please explicilty show the address value in question you are curious about.

Answer (score 0):

Referring the `%p` and what it prints:

The following code

```
void * p = 1;

printf("%p, %p\n", p, &p);
```

prints something like:

```
0000000000000001, 7fffffff0234585a
```

The first number is the value of `p` and the second number is where the first number is stored, this is the address of `p`. (As `p` is a pointer *both* values are addresses).

Comment: and what the difference ?and which one is correct ? @alk

Comment: The 1st `%p` prints the pointer `p`'s value, the `1`, the second `%p` prints the pointer `p`' s address (as evaluated by applying the `&` operator to `p`), the `7fffffff0234585a`.

Comment: @haccks: Because they are related to two fully different understandings of the problem. And "*two fully different understandings of the problem*" I consider as two questions, so I provided two answers ... :-)

Comment: This one here could have gone as a comment, but would have been too long anyways. @haccks